# Exporting from QGIS to ACAD DXF as Linework

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, dxf

I am attempting to export some QGIS (2.14.1) layers into AutoCAD (vanilla 2014) .dxf.  While I can do this by using the "Save As" feature, the problem I have is the elements export as solid hatch - no borders or line work that I can snap to in ACAD. It's as if QGIS is exporting the filled area and not the boundaries of the shapes as lines / polylines. I tried turning fill to 'transparent' under Layer Properties > Style, but that didn't help.

Any ideas? As AutoCAD users will know, hatches without borders drawn is essentially useless to work with or manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, try `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Polygons to lines`.

That way you get closed lines instead of filled polygons. If necessary, you might create polygons from them inside Autocad.

Answer (score 0):

In the QGIS menu go to Vectors-Geometry Tools-Polygons to Lines.  Run this tool on the layer you want to export, and then export the new vector layer instead of the original polygons.  You should then see only vectors instead of hatches.